# Dynamic Object Property Question with Reduce Function

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask a simple question about dynamic object properties.
In this example function I made, I noticed that I need square brackets between the cur.name variable but not for cur.age in the return statement. I found that it was something about dynamic object properties but was unsure of when I exactly need square brackets for parameters. Could I ask when I need square brackets?

Here is an example function:

```
const array = [
  {name: 'A', age: 1},
  {name: 'B', age: 2},
  {name: 'C', age: 3},
];

const example = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((acc, cur) => {return {...acc, [cur.name]: cur.age} }, {})
}

console.log(example(array));

//Output that I want is {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3} and it works.
```

Comment: The bracket notation is used to specify the key, were as `cur.age` is not a key, but just a prop on the object

Comment: So it is only for keys that I need bracket notations?